# DECLARING GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE

Tags: sql, db2-400, temporary

DB2/400 SQL : I'm working in a sql function witch is using a global temporary table.  I've juste a problem to declare this table : SQL send me an error, but i don't see where is the problem ? Can someone telle me what 's about this error ?

[Function with a declaring global temporary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuLg9.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include text version of the statement and error rather than a picture. That way I don't have to weed out the superfluous bits, and I can cut and paste it into my client for testing.

Comment: The function is created when I disable the declaration lines of my temporary table: the IBM doc does not indicate how to make this type of declaration in a function.

Comment: SQL procedures must be defined then compiled before you can use them.  It's not clear here what you are doing, which step you are on.  If you are trying to define it (run it as SQL) be aware the body of procedure contains semicolons so you have to change the SQL delimiter to something else before you run it.  I use '#' myself.  It should be on the last line in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak or read french, but it appears that the error is telling you that your function definition expects a return value, but the function body does not return anything.

Now when creating a SQL scalar function, the function body starts out with declarations. These declarations are for variables and cursors. It is somewhat unfortunate that you create a global temporary table using a statement that starts with `DECLARE`. It doesn't belong in the declarations but in the procedure body.

```
                      .-NOT ATOMIC-.   
>>-+--------+--BEGIN--+------------+---------------------------->
   '-label:-'         '-ATOMIC-----'   

>--+---------------------------------------+-------------------->
   | .-----------------------------------. |   
   | V                                   | |   
   '---+-SQL-variable-declaration--+-- ; +-'   
       +-SQL-condition-declaration-+           
       +-return-codes-declaration--+           
       '-INCLUDE-statement---------'           

>--+--------------------------------------+--------------------->
   | .----------------------------------. |   
   | V                                  | |   
   '---+-DECLARE CURSOR-statement-+-- ; +-'   
       '-INCLUDE-statement--------'           

>--+---------------------------------+-------------------------->
   | .-----------------------------. |   
   | V                             | |   
   '---+-handler-declaration-+-- ; +-'   
       '-INCLUDE-statement---'           

   .---------------------------------.                   
   V                                 |                   
>----+-----------------------------+-+--END--+-------+---------><
     '-SQL-procedure-statement-- ; '         '-label-'
```

It is part of the SQL procedure statement!

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've fixed this , but there is again the same problem : i can't declare a global temporary table in a SQL function...

Comment: The function is created when I disable the declaration lines of my temporary table: the IBM doc does not indicate how to make this type of declaration in a function.

Comment: It's OK : i found. The declare of the table must be behind the variables declare.

Comment: That's what I was just about to tell you. Just going to update this answer for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration section must come before the creation of any tables.

While it seems counter intuitive, DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE is not a normal variable declaration.

Try moving the other variable declarations above the table declaration.